# what will happen to the binary log if it reaches its maximum value ? Does it reset to mysql-bin.00001 again?

Tags: mysql, replication, binlog, mysqlbinlog

what will happen to the binary log if it reaches its maximum value ? Does it reset to mysql-bin.00001 again ?

I know the below points exist means, there won't be any reset happen in binlogs.

1. I would like to know whats the maximum value for the bin-log files.
2. In case, the expire_log_days not provided, then it should not replace the first file, throws 'file-exist' error.  The logs will be kept forever unless you specify an expiry.
3. If the binary log master  index files having the entry, I don't think it will replace.

Then what will happen eventually?

Comment: Do the math.  How many binlogs do you generate per day?  How many days before the number hits the max?  How many _years_ is that?

Answer (score 3):

If the binlog file number reaches its maximum value, it appears the server will throw an error.

However, the maximum value is not 999999 as it would appear ... it's 2,147,483,647.

From the source file `sql/log.h` (MySQL 5.6 source tree):

```
#define MAX_LOG_UNIQUE_FN_EXT 0x7FFFFFFF
```

Other relevant files are `sql/binlog.cc` and `sql/log.cc`.  The code that generates log file names zero-pads values to 6 digits after incrementing the current largest number by 1, but `sprintf(ext_buf, "%06lu", next)` will not truncate larger numbers, it just won't pad them... so `mysql-bin.999999` would be followed by `mysql-bin.1000000`.

And, according to the Google Machine, [somebody apparently tried it](http://adamcscott.blogspot.com/2014/06/mysql-55-maximum-sequence-in-binary-logs.html) just to make sure.

Comment: It means, it will throw error right.

Comment: It will continue growing past 6 digits and will not throw an error until mysql-bin.2147483647 is reached... over two billion binlogs.